# Google Cloud SQL CPU Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on trying to setup some monitoring on a Google Cloud SQL node and am not seeing how to do it.  I was able to install the monitoring agent on my Google Compute Engine instances to monitor CPU, Network, etc.  I have not been able to figure out how to do so on the Cloud SQL instance.  I have access to these types of monitoring:

- Storage Usage (GB)
- Number of Read/Write operations
- Egress Bytes
- Active Connections
- MySQL Queries
- MySQL Questions
- InnoDB Pages Read/Written (pages/sec)
- InnoDB Data fsyncs (operations/sec)
- InnoDB Log fsyncs (operations/sec)

I'm sure these are great options, but at this point all I want to pay attention to is if my node is performing on a CPU/RAM standpoint as they seem to first and foremost measures for performance.

If I'm missing something, or misunderstnading what I'm trying to do, any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't install the Cloud Monitoring agent on a CloudSQL instance, as you don't have access to the VM which the instance runs on. You are limited to the monitoring functions which are builtin. This may be a good feature to request on https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/list.

Answer (score 4):

Google has a Stackdriver which is for logging and monitoring Google and AWS cloud infrastructure. It can monitor every single thing present on GCP. You can create visualization to monitor your Cloud SQL instance in one dashboard. You just have to ---->
1. login to stackdriver and Go to any existing dashboard, If you dont have create one.---->
2. Add chart and select Cloud SQL in resource Name.---->
3. Select CPU Utilization from metric and save. You can also monitor memory, Disk I/o, Delta count of Queries or servers Up-time and many more.

if you want to monitor any other GCP Compute engine, App-Engine, Kubernetese Engine, storage bucket, Bigtable or pub/sub you just have to select appropriate resource name from list. Hope you got your answer.
[image]

Comment: Any idea if this would have an impact on Network egress bytes sent. We are suspecting it for the same causing lot of increased charges

Answer (score 0):

You can view all of them directly from the "Overview" tab of the Cloud SQL console:

[image]

Comment: These are the ones that I said I know how to do.  I don't see how these help me track on CPU or RAM usage.  I'm sure these all have an affect on the CPU and RAM usage, but I sure don't know how to measure "Egress Bytes" on a performance scale.

Comment: Sorry, my english isn't really good :) anyway isn't possibile to monitor cpu or ram: as @Adam says, try to open a feature request!

Answer (score 0):

I have added this as a feature request as issue 110.
https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=110