# Get Memory and Cpu Usages in Google Cloud Compute

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

How is one supposed to access the CPU usages and Memory usages of all the instances in a given project in Google Cloud Compute?

I'm unable to find anything regarding this in the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Google Cloud Monitoring](http://cloud.google.com/monitoring/) to see some usage metrics for your systems, and the [Google Cloud Monitoring agent](http://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/) to get more precise metrics like memory. [See the GCP metrics documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute) for a list of all available compute metrics.

Answer (score 5):

For memory usage on Debian:

```
free -m
```

in console.

Answer (score 3):

You can CPU, Memory, Network, Disk I/O related information of your instance group into Google Stackdriver. Stackdriver comes with a separate subscription. You can add charts to monitoring your GCP infrastructure into one single/multiple dashboard/s.

You can see detail information in [How to monitor GCP infrastructure using stack driver visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49127471/8575749)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Linux, you can install gnome-system-monitor and ssh -X into the system and launch it.

For Ubuntu on GCP:
"apt-get install gnome-system-monitor dbus"

From another linux machine (or if you have cygwin/x installed on windows), just "ssh -X {remote ip}"  Then type gnome-system-monitor and it will launch on your desktop.

You could also setup a vncserver on the cloud platform.